# What is the C++ equivalent of C#'s byte[,]?

Tags: c++

In C++, what the equivalent of C#'s `byte[,]`? I'm trying to do a conversion but I'm learning. Can anybody help?

Comment: You mean a 2d array of bytes?

Comment: Is it your intention/hope that the row-count can change, but the column count cannot during normal runtime? I.e. that you can expand or contract your table by rows, but not by columns once it has been initially constructed? (seems an odd question, I understand).

Comment: C# also supports jagged arrays, byte[][].  That will, in general, be a much better match for C arrays.  All of the answers you got are jagged arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate it using a few methods:

One: the recommended one using objects. Make a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector <std::vector < std::uint8_t > > twoDArr;
```

Two: the recommended way without objects - an array of bytes:

```
std::uint8_t arr[width][height];
```

(This one works in C as well.)

Three: in C, this is the only option for dynamically allocated arrays, but it's not recommended in C++ - just if you want C compatibility:

```
const size_t w = 13;
const size_t h = 37;
uint8_t **arr = malloc(w * sizeof(arr[0]));
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(h);
}
```

Comment: Only the second option is equivalent to C#'s `byte[,]`. A `byte[,]` is allocated as one large, contiguous chunk. Your first and third option don't satisfy this. (And if you see "contiguous" and go "whaaat??" when it comes to C#, remember: C# can access raw memory "unsafely" through pointers!)

Comment: @CoryNelson 1. I'm aware of that, that's why I used the term 'emulate'. 2. It seems OP is looking for a *functional* equivalent, i. e. not necessarily one that is *implemented* the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vector of vectors (2d vector)

To fill the 2d vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::uint8_t> > dynamicArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nCurrentWidth; ++i)
    {
      std::vector<std::uint8_t> row;
      for (int j = 0; j < m_nCurrentHeight; ++j)
      {
        row.push_back(0xFF);
      }

      dynamicArray.push_back(row);
    }
```

and to traverse it:

```
for (int y = 0; y < m_nCurrentHeight; ++y)
{
    const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& row = dynamicArray[y];
    for (int x=0; x < m_nCurrentWidth; ++x)
    {
       std::cout << row[x] << " ";
    }

  std::cout << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `std::vector<std::uint8_t> row(m_nCurrentHeight,0xFF);` should be enough for fill instead of for loop. Also for dynamicArray

Comment: +1 Nice tip, that work if you want to init the vector with the same value (like in the example), but if you want to init the vector with different values based on some logic, you need to loop, I just wanted to exemplify how you can dynamically add elements to the 2d vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >
```

Comment: You need to give it dimensions.

Comment: Use `std::uint8_t` instead.

Comment: @Pubby I would prefer `std::uint_least8_t` because `std::uint8_t` is an optional type.

Comment: @H2CO3 Because I misunderstood it, I see `std::array` is just for fixed size arrays ...

Comment: @sftrabbit Which is not guaranteed to be 8 bits (which is what `byte` is). `unsigned char` is likely better in such cases.

Comment: @Pubby a byte need not be 8 bits long, just like `char`.

Comment: @Pubby (and sftrabbit): uint8_t was my 1st thought but I remembered it usually needs `stdint.h` included which usually typedefs this as `unsigned char` (which is guaranteed to be 8 bits in size).

Comment: @H2CO3 But isn't a byte 8 bits by definition?? Am I missing something?

Comment: @g-makulik No. The word you're looking for is 'octet'. A byte can be any number of bits. There are/were architectures with 7, 8, 9 and even 12-bit wide bytes.

Comment: @g-makulik AFAIK, char is guaranteed to be one byte in size, but the standard does not define a byte as 8 bits, so in a specific implementation it could use 9 bits. The same should apply for unsigned char

Comment: The only thing guaranteed about `char` is that it is at least 8 bits and `sizeof(char) == 1`

Comment: @DanielCastro May be the C++ standard definition leaves this open, but there's no implementor seriously using this in a different way, does one?

Comment: @g-makulik I have not worked with this kind of platforms, but the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/bytes-review.html) talks about that

Comment: @DanielCastro OK, may be the FAQ mentions the potential ability. But at least I've never seen this in practice When I'm talking with FPGA or other hardware developers the common consensus is that a `byte` **means** 8 bit. If we don't have 8 bits we'll call it s.th. different for sure.

Comment: @g-makulik Yes, byte is now usually used to mean 8 bits. Anyway, C++ Standard stil understands byte 'the old way', so it doesn't (necessarily) means 8 bits there

Comment: @DanielCastro But at least, assuming C# is implemented correctly on such platforms that have bytes of other size than 8 bits, the **equivalent** still is `unsigned char`, right?

Comment: @g-makulik I would think so :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just create an array like this.

```
    unsigned char byteArray[][];
```

And you can instantiate it like this.

```
    byteArray = {{byte1A,byte1B},{byte2A,byte2B},...,{byteNA,byteNB}};
```

Comment: Except that neither one compiles... -.-